# How to calculate the emissivity of a metal from first principles?

Tags: solid-state-physics

I wonder how to calculate the emissivity of a metal (or a conductor if you prefer) starting from first principles. I.e. starting from a solid state physics model of a metal (for instance a Fermi gas or liquid with lattice interactions and/or electron-phonon interactions). I do not really know which parameters have a noticeable effect on the emissivity.

So, how would one do it?

Comment: You need to know the complex refractive index. This requires an ab initio calculation on the material, such as a crystal local density calculation.

Comment: How does the knowledge of $\epsilon(\omega)$ helps in calculating $\epsilon_{S-B}$? I did not know there was a relation between the two. Do you have any source about it I could check?